# File type check SVN hook

Tags: svn, build-process, build-automation

I was search for two hours for SVN hook shell script which can do below two things and I am not able to find. Could you please help me if you have any relative template or materials.

1. Need to check file type(*.java, *.css, *.js...)
2. Need to add at top of file when ever file committed

   /*
        * Copyright (c) 1994, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
        * ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
        *  author:
        * file version:
        * file pathname:
        * and any other tags that might be useful.
        */

Answer (score 3):

1. In the script use [`svnlook`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnlook.html) to analyze incoming transaction and implement a logic whether to reject or allow the commit.
2. You must not do this. See [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks):

   > While hook scripts can do almost anything, there is one dimension in
   >   which hook script authors should show restraint: **do not modify a
   >   commit transaction using hook scripts**. While it might be tempting to
   >   use hook scripts to automatically correct errors, shortcomings, or
   >   policy violations present in the files being committed, doing so can
   >   cause problems. Subversion keeps client-side caches of certain bits of
   >   repository data, and if you change a commit transaction in this way,
   >   those caches become indetectably stale. This inconsistency can lead to
   >   surprising and unexpected behavior. **Instead of modifying the
   >   transaction, you should simply validate the transaction in the
   >   pre-commit hook and reject the commit if it does not meet the desired
   >   requirements**. As a bonus, your users will learn the value of
   >   careful, compliance-minded work habits.

Comment: I found solution, Actually we are not using hook scprits instead of that we are going to use svn tokens, it looks like this.

Answer (score 1):

i found solution but not with hook scripts. i did with svn tokens.

1. Need to attach(activate) needed tokens to particular project or folder in svn using some SVN clients.
2. Need to write a template like this.

   /* *

   - Copyright (c) 1992-2013 XXXX, Inc and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
   - XXXX  PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms
   - Last Modified By   :$Author$
   - Modified Time      :$Date$
   - File Version       :$Revision$
   - File Path          :$URL$
     */
3. First time you have to add this template to your source code. And commit, next time you don't need to do.
4. Notice: the template need to be change base one file time. the above template for .java files, you have to change if you want to apply for .xml or other based on the comment syntax of the particular technology.
5. Just commit....   Done..